# How to find percentages using groupby in pandas - not total, but instead individual neighborhood filters

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, percentage

I have a pandas df which I have grouped (using groupby) neighborhood and attendance to doctors meetings. indicated by 0/1 (Yes/No, respectively).

I would like to know the percentage of individuals who go to the doctor meeting BY neighborhood.

```
PatientId   AppointmentID   Gender  ScheduledDay    AppointmentDay  Age Neighbourhood   Scholarship Hipertension    Diabetes    Alcoholism  Handcap SMS_received    No-show

5642903 1   2016-04-29T18:38:08Z    2016-04-29T00:00:00Z    62  JARDIM DA PENHA                  0           1      0        
 0             0                   1
```

I have tried

```
print (100 * df['No-show'].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

which gives me total attendance, not filtered  by Neighboorhood.

I have also tried

```
df['Percent'] = df.groupby('Neighbourhood')['No-show'].transform(lambda x: sum(x)/ count(x))
```

where of course count(x) causes an error --but I cannot figure how else to use it.

```
 df['Percent'] = df.groupby('Neighbourhood')['No-show'].transform(lambda x: sum(x)/ count(x))
```

I would like to know the percentage of individuals who go to the doctor meeting BY neighborhood.